# test custom extensions with jest

Tags: node.js, regex, jestjs

I want to test all `.ut.js` files.

See below what I've tried and the output. what am I missing? I tested the regex(es) so I know that is not the problem.

I also tried passing the flags `testRegex` and `testMatch` and getting `zsh: no matches found: ...`

```
$ yarn jest '**\/*\.ut\.js'
yarn jest v0.24.6
$ "/home/goldylucks/apps/ci-workflow-workshop/node_modules/.bin/jest" **\/*\.ut\.js
  Invalid testPattern **/*.ut.js supplied. Running all tests instead.

$ yarn jest '**\/\.ut\.js'
yarn jest v0.24.6
$ "/home/goldylucks/apps/ci-workflow-workshop/node_modules/.bin/jest" **\/\.ut\.js
  Invalid testPattern **/.ut.js supplied. Running all tests instead.

$ yarn jest '\.ut\.js'
yarn jest v0.24.6
$ "/home/goldylucks/apps/ci-workflow-workshop/node_modules/.bin/jest" \.ut\.js
No tests found
In /home/goldylucks/apps/ci-workflow-workshop
  32 files checked.
  testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.js?(x),**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x) - 1 match
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 32 matches
Pattern: ".ut.js" - 0 matches
Done in 0.61s.

$ yarn jest '\.ut\.'  
yarn jest v0.24.6
$ "/home/goldylucks/apps/ci-workflow-workshop/node_modules/.bin/jest" \.ut\.
No tests found
In /home/goldylucks/apps/ci-workflow-workshop
  32 files checked.
  testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.js?(x),**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x) - 1 match
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 32 matches
Pattern: ".ut." - 0 matches
Done in 0.60s.
```

Comment: Is your issue that you are only including `(spec|test).js?x` files in the test suite? So, the `.ut.js` filter returns zero results, because these files were never getting included to begin with?

Comment: And I think the optimum pattern you need is: `yarn jest '\\.ut\\.js$'`

Comment: `yarn jest '\\.ut\\.js$' testMatch src` worked! thank u @tom